# Linux route LAN to wireless

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a home network setup like this:

```
[Broadband Modem] <-> {[Linux NIC1/NAT] <-> [Linux NIC2]} <-> [Wireless Router]
                                               |
                                            [Wired LAN]
```

The curly braces represent a single PC.

For years I've run this way, with Wireless Router as an Access Point.

My problems were introduced yesterday when I wanted to fix a wifi deadspot, and upgraded to a Mesh Wireless Router. Unfortunately I found the Mesh feature is only supported in Router mode, and not in Access Point mode.

So now I have two DHCP servers - the Linux box, and now the new Mesh Router.

It all works, except wired LAN traffic on Linux NIC2 cannot reach wireless clients anymore.

NIC2 is 192.168.2.x, with Wireless Router "Internet" side at 192.168.2.2, and the wireless network is 192.168.3.x.

I thought I just needed an `ip route add 192.168.3.0/24 dev eth0 via 192.168.2.2` but that doesn't help.

Suggestions?

Comment: is your new router an enterprise router, or a consumer grade internet access router? if its the later, are you using the WAN port, or just the LAN ports?

Comment: consumer grade - the wireless router is a tplink Archer A7 (AC1750). I don't have a lot of settings in its UI, but I did switch off the WAN firewall. I am only using it for wireless. The wired LAN ports are unused (although they'd just join the 192.168.3.x subnet).

Comment: consider plugging the upstream network into the LAN port instead. The issue isn't the firewall, its the NAT. The firewall can be configured, but if you don't have an option to disable the NAT, then the best you can do is forward ports from the wireless network to the wired one, and each port can be used by at most 1 wireless device.

Comment: Thanks. Or, try to find a proper access point that supports mesh. :-)

Comment: agreed, if that is an option for you, an AP that works like you want is definitely the best approach.